# Webpack error: static bundle throwing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" when console is open or sometimes not predictable

Tags: javascript, webpack, production-environment

Bundled my react code using webpack 4, and deployed it on GCP bucket. It's throwing error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" sometimes or when developer tools is open not sure about pattern.

I tried to regenerate pattern of error but couldn't find. I thought its issue of caching and tried ?v=1 not worked(infact in incognito error is there)

When i tried same production bundle.js on my local machine its working absolutely fine.

Here is my webpack code for production

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: [
           'style-loader',
           'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
              {loader: "style-loader"},
              {loader: "css-loader"},
              {loader: "sass-loader"}
          ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      sourceMap: true
    })
  ]
};
```